# Is it possible to consolidate arguments in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

In the application I'm working on, someone else on the team wrote some code to populate cells in Excel like this:

```
sheet[1, 4] = "This is text"
```

That would fill out the first row, fourth column with "This is text".

I was thinking it might be neat to store that in a variable of some sort:

```
sheet[NAMED_CELL] = "This is text"
```

I don't know how I would set `NAMED_CELL` though. I tried simply doing:

```
NAMED_CELL = 1, 4
```

But that didn't work.

**Is something like this possible?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "splat" operator to destructure an array of values into individual arguments:

```
x = [1,4]

cells[*x] = "This is text" # identical to cells[1,4]
```

The syntax you're trying to use, `x = 1,4` cannot work. You cannot store two values in a variable without *some* kind of container such as an array, hash or class.

Comment: That is super cool. Learned something new today. Thanks much!